# jQuery "undefined" prints when appending to html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a jQuery MP3 player. The song structure is first generated (including the information about the song), and then the structure is appended to a div using jQuery like this:

```
function loadFromPlaylist(playlist) {
    var songsStructure;

    for (var i=0; i<playlist.length; i++) {
        songsStructure +=
        "<div id='song" + i + "'>" +
            "<span class='mpPlaylistArtist'>" + playlist[i].artist + "</span>" +
            "<span class='mpPlaylistSong'>" + playlist[i].song + "</span>" +
            "<span class='mpPlaylistAlbum'>" + playlist[i].album + "</span>" +
        "</div>";
    }

    $('#mpTracks').append(songsStructure);
}
```

This works perfectly except for one thing. When the items are displayed in the browser, a string ("undefined") is printed above the songs, like so:

```
<div id="mpTracks">
    "undefined"
    <div id="song0">...</div>
    <div id="song1">...</div>
</div>
```

Googling this problem yielded alot of related problems but that didn't help me.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Did you tried giving a default value for the songStructure?

Comment: @Ajai the problem has been solved. I just needed to initialize the variable :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Initialize your variable to an empty string, before using it:

```
var songsStructure = '';
```

You did not set an initial value, so it is set to `undefined`. According to JS rules for concatination, this `undefined`is then concatenated with the strings generated by the `for` loop leading to your result.

Comment: Man you are the best! Thanks for the explanation as well!

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You have to initialize the `songsStructure` variable.

Write

```
 function loadFromPlaylist(playlist) {
        var songsStructure="";
```

and your problem will be solved.