# jQuery “undefined” prints when .html().show() is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am concatenating using an variable and it will only print undefined.
I have looked for hours for the solution and haven't found the reason closest was form this question [jQuery "undefined" prints when appending to html element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433171/jquery-undefined-prints-when-appending-to-html-element) but the solutions give have still not worked.

Please help and explain so I can learn and understand.
thank you.
my code below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var nam="";
$("#sayHello").click(function(){
    nam = $("textBox1").val();
    if(nam != ""){
        $("#welcome").html("<p>Hello "+ nam +"</p>").show;
    }
    ;});


});
```

this is my jquery/javascript
and here is my html

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="inputBox">
    Here is my first text box.
    <input id="textBox1" type="text" value=""/>

    <button id="sayHello">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <div id="welcome">
    </div>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myJQ.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: The question you mentioned is irrelevant, because they use `+=` on an uninitialized variable. You don’t. In your title it says `.html().show()`, but in your code it says `.html(`…`).show`. The final `.show` doesn’t do anything if it’s not called.

Comment: you have a missing `#` in your id selector `nam = $("textBox1").val();`, should be `nam = $("#textBox1").val();`

Comment: @am05mhz thank you. I need to need to start using a better IDE that will catch small things like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edit your code try it

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var nam="";
$("#sayHello").click(function(){
    nam = $("#textBox1").val();
    if(nam){
        $("#welcome").html("Hello "+nam)
    }
    });


});
```

```html
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="inputBox">
    Here is my first text box.
    <input id="textBox1" type="text"/>

    <button id="sayHello">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <div id="welcome">
    </div>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myJQ.js"></script>
</body>
```